# WhatsApp voice notes are not working

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

The voice notes are working if I hear them through WhatsApp, but in storage, they are named "PTT......opus." but still aren't working. The device says there is no application to do this action.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The **.opus** format is the new audio format that WhatsApp uses to record voice notes. The previous format was **.m4a**. So in order to listen to your voice notes, you'll need to change the extension **.opus** to a supported one, such as mp3 (Your phone file explorer may not permit that, so you need to download a third party app, such as *ES File Explorer* on Google play.